# how to turn a string into an image url that is the first search result

Tags: javascript, html, search, request

I'm making a visual representation of an object database.

I want the **img** element to be the first image result from a web search.

I've been trying to use wikipedia, but I'm missing a few steps.
Here's what I got:

```js
var searchLink = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/“;
var subject = "goblin";
searchLink += subject;

//QUESTION: how do it make an image request with the searchLink?

//I've been trying to access the direct link to the image
var classTag = document.getElementsByClassName("floatnone");
var imageTag = classTag[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
var imageLink = imageTag[0].href; //value becomes "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Goya_-_Caprichos_(49).jpg"
```

Any ideas on how to turn a **string** into **the first image url** of that **string search**?

Comment: do you want to download image?

Comment: I want to get the image url to use as the source for my html img element @SaidKholov

Comment: create img tag and put your url to src element like this. `document.getElementById("imageid").src=url`

Comment: Thanks @SaidKholov , that helps, but it's not the core of the question.
What I'm trying to figure out is how to:
1- given a string
2 - make a google or wikipedia search
3 - grab the first image result of that search
4 - return the url for that image